# "Cannot deconstruct an array as an object"

Tags: json, postgresql

I have the following query

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * from "Table0"        
    UNION SELECT * from "Table1" 
    UNION SELECT * from "Table2" 
    UNION SELECT * from "Table3" 
    UNION SELECT * from "Table4" 
    UNION SELECT * from "Table5") as req 
    join lateral json_each_text(previewcontent::json) j on true where j.value like '%0.0'
```

`PreviewContent` is a `jsonb` field.

But Postgres returns the following error:

```
ERROR: cannot deconstruct an array as an object
SQL state: 22023
```

I don't know why. 
This request was working few days ago.

Comment: `json_each_text` needs an object, not an array. So your error seems obvious and just looking at the values of previewcontent would confirm that (do all values start with a `{`?).

Comment: 22023  is `invalid_parameter_value` -
 https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/errcodes-appendix.html

Answer (score 5):

## Postgres 9.6+

From array: `unnest`. Eg.: `SELECT unnest(ARRAY['my', 'nice', 'command'])`

Ref: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-array.html

## Postgres 10+

From json: `json_array_elements_text`. Eg.: `SELECT json_array_elements_text('["my", "nice", "command"]'::json)`

Ref: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html